# Would training 1024x1024 images with pretrained resnet (224x224) be appropriate?

Tags: transfer-learning, pre-training

I want to use Resnet50 (or 101, or 152..) backbone for a segmentation task. My problem requires a lot of context, hence tiling the large image into 224x224 defeats the purpose.

I was wondering if I can utilize the pretrained network, mainly for convergence speed?

I imagine the features extracted from 224x224 images would not match with 1024x1024 images, due to scale. But I am not sure if a proper fine tuning (=a lot of epochs of training) can compensate for that. Or since the solution found from 224 images are too different, finding appropriate features for high resolution images too time consuming/not possible due to local minima issues etc?